# Get network address of connected interface with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, scapy

How could I get the current network address of a specific interface (not the ip address, but the network address) ?

For example, if I run the following command on terminal `ip a show <interace> | grep inet`
I get a result similar to this.n**n**

```
    inet 192.168.43.157/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
    inet6 fe80::6877:db06:4b23:7a7c/64 scope link noprefixroute
```

In this example my current IP address is **192.168.45.157/24** but the network address (which I am looking for) is **192.168.43.0/24**.

How I would get the network address ?

Comment: I believe the OP is looking get this information in Python, which makes the question more programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use the [`netaddr`](https://pypi.org/project/netaddr/) module:

```
>>> x = netaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.45.157/24')
>>> x.cidr
IPNetwork('192.168.45.0/24')
```

Or you can just convert the address into a 32 bit number, convert the prefix into a bitmask, and then apply to the mask:

```
>>> import socket
>>> addr = '192.168.45.157/24'
>>> ip, prefix = addr.split('/')
>>> mask = 0xFFFFFFFF << (32-int(prefix))
>>> bin(mask)
'0b1111111111111111111111111111111100000000'
>>> ip_bytes = socket.inet_aton(ip)
>>> '.'.join(str(int(x)) for x in struct.pack('>I', struct.unpack('>I', ip_bytes)[0] & mask))
'192.168.45.0'
```